# TaskAwaiter<IUserContactsCollectionPage> not implement INotifyCompletion

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to interface my software(asp.net webForms site, based in 4.6.1 Framework) with a Microsoft account via Graph. I successfully get the token, I instantiate the GraphServiceClient object but then I can't make calls to read or write data. This is the code:

```
public static async Task<IUserContactsCollectionPage> GetContactsAsync(Conn conn, string id)
{
    string token = GetToken(conn, id);
    var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient(token);

    var contacts = await graphClient.Me.Contacts.Request()
        .OrderBy("surname ASC")
        .GetAsync();

    return contacts;
}
```

here I have the error:

```
var contacts = await graphClient.Me.Contacts.Request()
        .OrderBy("surname ASC")
        .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Are you [calling `Result` or `Wait` further up your call stack](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)?

Comment: This is a compilation error not a runtime error

Comment: So... what's the error?

Comment: the title of the post, so: TaskAwaiter<IUserContactsCollectionPage> not implement INotifyCompletion